# How to create new fake image using GANS given the trained generator model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on this tutorial: https://colab.research.google.com/github/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/t81_558_class_07_2_Keras_gan.ipynb#scrollTo=1yqlUD4sdiDk in which I am trying to train a GAN including a Generator and Discriminator model. This is my first GAN project, so I am new to all this.

I am able to run this code from start to end but somehow I am not clear on two aspects:

1. There are two kernels with the following code and I am not sure what this code is actually doing. I hope someone can explain.
   [image]

[image]

2. How to actually general new fake images given the trained Generator Model? I am not sure if this tutorial is doing that or if I am misunderstanding and it actually is being done. I hope someone can clairfy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generator portion of a GAN takes in noise and produces a new fake image, this is what's happening on lines 2 and 3 of your first section, and then to display the image you have `plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0])`

The second section you have is the discriminator, which is used to try and classify your generated images as either real or fake, this helps the generator generate better fake images.

Comment: How would I generate a new fake image from the trained model? I am not sure how to configure the seed etc. I hope you can assist.

Answer (score 2):

The image at the start of the Google Colab notebook is meant to explain the main idea behind GANs and the first part of the code in your 1. question

[image]

1. GANs use two Neural Networks (Discriminator and Generator) to train together. Generator converts random noise (or Random Seed as in image) into a visual representation (in this case, in general GANs can be used to generate other types of data). Discriminator is used only in training, as a control to tell Generator how well it is doing at converting Random Seed into a convincing simulation of data you're trying to simulate (in this case a human face). For this you also need to train Discriminator alongside to make it better at detecting simulated data (it can be relatively easy to detect simulated data at first), but since you're only interested in generating new data once the model is done training, this part is not used after training.

   The first part of your 1. code is meant to display what an untrained Generator
   outputs (input is Random Seed, output is an incoherent image).

   The second part of your 1. code is meant to display what an untrained
   Discriminator outputs (using a generated image as input, it outputs probability of it being a real image and not a simulated one).
2. For second part of your question, you just need to follow this logic further. Once trained, you don't need the Discriminator (as you're interested in generating new data, and don't need Discriminator to tell you if it's real or not). So, you just need to input new Random Seed (same shape as Random Seed they used in the tutorial to train the models) into Generator, and it should output a generated image.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The only question I had is how you would generate a new trained image from the trained generator model using a new random input seed. I am not too sure how that would look like..i hope you can help.

Comment: You can use the first part of 1. question code:
`noise = tf.random.normal([1,SEED_SIZE])` generates a new Random Seed,
`generated_image = generator(noise, training = False)` generates a new image,
if you want to see it you can continue on with `plt.imshow(generated_image[0,:,:,0])`

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the random seed, If I have an image of myself, can I feed my pic into the generator model and then it outputs an altered version of me OR are the input of pictures not in my control due to the random seed?

Comment: Random Seed is an array of numbers, not an image. You can't feed an image to Generator in this case, because that's not what it was trained to do. If you want a model that can do that, you need to look for a different approach (style transfer might be one of them, but it depends on what you're trying to do).